# Ember. Routes. The same name in nested routes, routes lookup

Tags: ember.js

Is it impossible to have nested routes with the same names? For example:

```
// url - category/12345/card/id99
this.resource('category', { path: '/category/:category_id' }, function () {
    this.resource('card', { path: 'card/:card_id' });
});

// url - semantic/books/card/id99
this.resource('semantic', { path: '/semantic/:semantic_id' }, function () {
    this.resource('card', { path: 'card/:card_id' });
});
```

When I call **transitionTo('card')** router lookups only last version of route **'card'**

Looks like router has plain routes list and routes with the same names constantly overriden by last.

I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, for version v.1 it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine hitting 'card/:card_id' directly in the browser. The router cannot differentiate the context of that route from one parent or another.  A more appropriate way to handle this issue pointed out in your related question ([Ember. Making modal view that has its own route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19087728/1315694)) would be to have a separate route that you pass a 'previous route' context to.

Comment: At the browser I have 2 urls that is perfectly differentiated currently in Ember. Because of prefix /semantic or /category.
I have it worked now. Because I give them different names.
But it's impossible to have the same name.

And you are right, anyway I have to build context if I want to perform transitionTo().